# Update column with data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update the value in column `TOTAL_DURATION` from table `IAM_RSP_INSTRUCTION`, where the value of `TOTAL_DURATION` is based on the query

```
select (paid_rsp + rd) as total from 
(
  select count (b.rsp_instruction_id) as paid_rsp, a.rsp_duration as rd,
    b.rsp_instruction_id
  from IAM_RSP_INSTRUCTION a
  JOIN IAM_BUY_FUND_INFO b on a.RSP_ID = b.RSP_INSTRUCTION_ID
  where b.RSP_INSTRUCTION_ID is not null
  and a.rsp_status= 'approved' or a.rsp_status='terminated' 
  group by a.rsp_duration, b.rsp_instruction_id, a.rsp_status<br>
  HAVING a.rsp_duration > -1
  order by b.rsp_instruction_id
) ,
and rsp_id from IAM_RSP_INSTRUCTION = rsp_instruction_id
from IAM_BUY_FUND_INFO
```

Currently, I have an update query:

```
UPDATE IAM_RSP_INSTRUCTION
SET j.TOTAL_DURATION = (
  select (paid_rsp + rd)  as total
  from (
    select count (b.rsp_instruction_id) as paid_rsp, a.rsp_duration as rd,
      b.rsp_instruction_id 
    from iam_rsp_instruction a
    JOIN iam_buy_fund_info b on a.RSP_ID = b.RSP_INSTRUCTION_ID
    where b.RSP_INSTRUCTION_ID is not null
    and a.rsp_status= 'approved' or a.rsp_status='terminated'
    group by a.rsp_duration, b.rsp_instruction_id, a.rsp_status
    HAVING a.rsp_duration > -1
    order by b.rsp_instruction_id
  )
  WHERE IAM_RSP_INSTRUCTION.rsp_id = rsp_instruction_id
);
```

When i run the query, after 8 hours, it still running and no records be updated. 
Note: The subquery worked when I ran it.

```
select (paid_rsp + rd) as total from 
    (
      select count (b.rsp_instruction_id) as paid_rsp, a.rsp_duration as rd,
        b.rsp_instruction_id
      from IAM_RSP_INSTRUCTION a
      JOIN IAM_BUY_FUND_INFO b on a.RSP_ID = b.RSP_INSTRUCTION_ID
      where b.RSP_INSTRUCTION_ID is not null
      and a.rsp_status= 'approved' or a.rsp_status='terminated' 
      group by a.rsp_duration, b.rsp_instruction_id, a.rsp_status<br>
      HAVING a.rsp_duration > -1
      order by b.rsp_instruction_id
    )
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? sql srver <> oracle. And you need to define "not working".

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: Get your query working right first, then figure out how to use it in the update - you need to correlate the data from the table you're updating with the subquery you're using.

Comment: No error  message.  Just is when i run the query, after 8 hours, it still running and no records be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shot with the fix for the most visible issues I can found. If you provide table structure and some samples, this could be tested.

```
UPDATE IAM_RSP_INSTRUCTION j 
   SET j.TOTAL_DURATION = (select (paid_rsp + rd)  as total 
                             from (select count (b.rsp_instruction_id) as paid_rsp, 
                                          a.rsp_duration as rd,
                                          b.rsp_instruction_id 
                                     from iam_rsp_instruction a 
                                          JOIN 
                                          iam_buy_fund_info b 
                                          on a.RSP_ID = b.RSP_INSTRUCTION_ID
                                    where b.RSP_INSTRUCTION_ID is not null 
                                      and (a.rsp_status= 'approved' 
                                       or a.rsp_status='terminated')
                                      and b.rsp_instruction_id = j.rsp_id
                                 group by a.rsp_duration,
                                          b.rsp_instruction_id, 
                                          a.rsp_status 
                                   HAVING a.rsp_duration > -1));
```